# Pull to refresh: screen disappears

Tags: ios, objective-c, pull-to-refresh

I implemented `pull to refresh` functionality for my controller:

```
- viewDidLoad {
self.refresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[self.refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshData) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.tableView addSubview:self.refresh];
}

- (void) refreshData {
__weak myController *weakSelf = self;
[[NetworkcallManager instance] getCall:^(NSString *result){
    if(weakSelf != nil) {
                [weakSelf.refresh endRefreshing];
                [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
            }
    }];
}
```

The refresh works as expected, but when I pull down the screen too hard then the entire screen disappears for a moment and then the data gets refreshed.

**Is there a way to avoid disappearance of the screen?** I am wondering if it is because of reloadData function. In case it calls '`viewWillAppear`' then I can understand the problem I am facing. (My viewWillAppear code results in momentarily blank screen).

Edit:
If I pull down without internet connection (turned off the wifi) then the screen doesn't disappear.

Comment: Do you get any AutoLayout error?

Comment: No, I don't. Everything works fine with a blank screen for just a moment.

Comment: try to reload your tableView in main thread -     `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [weakSelf.refresh endRefreshing];
        [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
    });`

Comment: Tried this as well. But still the screen disappears.

Comment: I got the issue. In the code I am purging the table and then updating it. As a result, the screen disappears momentarily.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would transcribe your comment into an answer and accept it. That flags the question as "answered" in the system, and helps future searchers discover something that might help them with similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue. In the code I am purging the table and then updating it. As a result, the screen disappears momentarily.